# How to join each double lines?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, text-processing

I have a text file,

```
a1
a2
b1
b2
c1
c2
...
```

I want to join by two lines so one can `sort` it:

```
a1:a2
b1:b2
c1:c2
...
```

I'm using bash. the `read` function will eat the leading space, which is undesired. And I hate to write simple stupid C programs.

Then, I can use `tr : "\n"` to split the joined file back to two files.

Comment: “I hate to write simple stupid C program” – easy. Learn a scripting language. That’s what they’re there for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`paste -s -d ':\n' file` should do it.

For example:

```
% cat f
a1
a2
b1
b2
% paste -s -d ':\n' f
a1:a2
b1:b2
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sed 'N;s/\n/:/;' < srcfile > destfile
```

Comment: No need for input redirection, `sed` accepts a filename as an argument. The final semicolon is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Looking [over there](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt) I found an example that can be converted into:

```
sed '$!N;s/\n/:/' < file
```

Comment: No need for input redirection, `sed` accepts a filename as an argument. The `$!` is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

```
INDEX=0
A=""
B=""

for i in `awk '{print $1}' input`
    do
    if [ $INDEX -eq 0 ]; then
        A=$i;
        let INDEX=1;
    fi

    if [ $INDEX -eq 1 ]; then
        B=$i;
        echo $A:$B
        let INDEX=0;
    fi
done
```

Comment: @Dennis Williamson thought I read he wanted it in BASH, but yeah, if only AWK it would be a piece of cake.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{line=$0; printf line; if (getline) printf ":" $0; print ""}' inputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

edit in-place with backup:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/\n\Z/:/ if $.%2' file
```

edit in-place no backup:

```
perl -i -pe 's/\n\Z/:/ if $.%2' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

def njoin(filename, outfn="", n=3, linesuffix=" "):
    if not outfn:
        outfn = filename + ".join"
    with open(filename) as infh, open(outfn, "w") as outfh:
        nline = 0
        for line in infh:
            if nline % n != n-1:
                line = line.rstrip() + linesuffix
            outfh.write(line)
            nline += 1
```

In you case you can use the function like this:

```
njoin("/path/to/file", n=2, linesuffixe=":")
```